# Dynamically pass sharepoint list name in ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-list, datasource

I want to pass Dynamic SharePoint list name. I want to give access to users to provide the parameter value in ssrs report for SharePoint list and get the data. So, to dynamically pass the data i am using fx expression. But when i hit okay i don't see any fields.

```
="<RSSharePointList xmlns:xsi=" & 
"""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""" &
"  xmlns:xsd=" &
"""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""" & ">" & vbcrlf &
"<ListName>"@parameter"</ListName>" & vbcrlf &
"<ViewFields>" & vbcrlf &
    "<FieldRef Name=" &
    """Team""" &
    " />" & vbcrlf &
"</ViewFields>" & vbcrlf &
"</RSSharePointList"
```

Answer (score 0):

You either have to create your dataset with the “hard coded” xml first and let the SSRS designer get the fields from one of the lists, then change it back to the expression, or you can map the fields manually on the Fields tab.